# Regular Expression to match a single word separated by dot or only allow asterisk

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression that allows only one asterisk or a work separated by dot and one asterisk at the end. For example:

```
test.test   = OK
test.test*  = OK
*           = OK

.                       = NO
_                       = NO
test.*                  = NO
test.test               = OK
test.test2              = OK
test*                   = OK
te*st                   = NO
test*.test              = NO
```

This is what I did so far

```
^[a-z0-9*.\-_\.:]+$
```

The non character to allow are dots and one asterisk
The character to allow are lower case

Comment: Show us, what  you have already tried.

Comment: "Only one asterisk *or* a word separated by dot." Your second example `test.test*` includes one asterisk AND a word separated by a dot. Can you clarify?

Comment: @RobertAKARobin updated

Comment: ... and from your regex, I guess you want some characters to be allowed and others not. Please specify precisely what chars you accept and which not.

Comment: Here's a regex101 y'all can chew on: https://regex101.com/r/QnhHJj/1

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am going to try it. Please post it and I will accept.

Comment: Well, it's your original regex; it doesn't do what you want.  But you can study the matches, and the right-hand side gives you a complete breakdown of exactly what the regex is doing as you modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want either:

- 1 asterisk *or*
- a dot separated sequence of words, only the last of which can be followed by an asterisk

`^((\*)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\*?)$`

Please note that `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` should be adapted to what you really mean as a word. In my answer it is simply one or more alfanumeric chars.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this one**

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+?\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+?\*?$|^\*$
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+?` - Matches any alphabet or digit one or more time (lazy mode).(? makes it optional)
- `\.?` - Matches `.` .
- `\*?` - Matches `*`.
- `$` - End of string.
- `|` - Alternation.
- `^\*$` - Matches `*`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m8Y0Pp/1/)

Let me know if i missed any case.